# Корова и каравай

Tags: этимология

Я где-то читала, что слово "каравай" как-то связано со словом "корова". А можно узнать об этом подробнее? Какая связь может быть между праздничным хлебом и коровой?
Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из Интернета

Символика свадебного каравая сочетает в себе женское и мужское начала. Изначально слово писалось и произносилось как «коровай» и этимологически было связано с лексемой «корова». Такое написание можно встретить, например, у Гоголя. Только позднее в процессе закрепления аканья в письменной речи «коровай» превратился в «каравай». Корова олицетворяла собой женское начало, а суффикс «-ай» являлся символом мужчины-быка. В этой связи не случайными оказываются украшения каравая скрученными из теста рожками.

Answer (score 1):

Могу выдвинуть другую версию . Слово КАРАВАЙ очень неплохо вписывается в еврейское имя ХАРИВ , - ХАРИВ-АЙ . При этом надо обратить внимание , что еврейская буква **כ** имеет двойное звучание - как Х и как К , а также и то , что в иврите нет гласных букв . Поэтому еврейские имена в разных локальных диалектах всегда варьировались : ХАРИВ мог звучать , как КАРИВ , ХАРАВ , КАРАВ . От этого же имени происходят такие фамилии как Кравчук , Кравченко , Кривенцев , Кривенец . Что же касается КАРАВАЯ , то можно предположить , что когда-то давно жил пекарь-еврей по имени Харив=Карив=Карав , который и запустил это хлебобулочное изделие в производство , и оно стало называться его именем . Что же касается написания через "о" и украшений в виде рожек , то это просто , так сказать , народная этимология этого слова . Аналогично от еврейских имен происходят такие термины гастрономии как салат , винигрет , коржик , лапша и др. Среди ремесленников было много евреев , и их имена ( обычно , в несколько искаженном виде) превратились в названия ремеслянных изделий и инструментов : сорочка  , черевички , штаны , рубанок , стамеска , сверло , шведский ключ . Или вот ещё слово "шептало" : это в оружейном деле - пружинчатый механизм , который возвращает курок в исходное положение . Может показаться , что это шептало что-то там *шепчет* . Да , ничего оно не *шепчет* - просто еврейское имя Йепет(ветх.зав. Иафет) у немецких ашкеназов звучало как Дшепет ; по-видимому , так звали того мастера-механика , который наладил в России изготовление этих шептал . А вот слово "халява" ; так в старину называлось стекольное производство . Несомненно тут присутствует еврей по имени Халев .

Comment: Если "слово КАРАВАЙ очень неплохо вписывается в еврейское имя ХАРИВ", тогда слова КРОВ и КРОВЬ тоже очень неплохо вписываются в еврейское имя ХАРИВ.

Если "слово КАРАВАЙ очень неплохо вписывается в еврейское имя ... ХАРИВ-АЙ", тогда слова КРОВАТЬ тоже очень неплохо вписывается в еврейское имя ...  ХАРИВ-АТЬ.

Answer (score 0):

Версия номер три: слово *каравай* замечательно живет в английском языке, в котором оно значит "тмин" (его, по-моему, в каравай и кладут).
Проследив этимологию английского слова через латынь и греческий, можно придти к санскритскому слову "карави", которое, по-видимому, оную специю и обозначало — иногда ее называют "персидская зира".
В семитских языках тоже есть похожие слова, но кто у кого их занял, индоевропейцы у семитов или наоборот, — это слишком давняя история.

Comment: Придти к санскритскому слову "карави" забывши про давнюю историю с коровой.